# How to round a value of type Measurement using MeasurementFormatter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rounding, foundation, measurement

I need to round a value of type `Measurement<UnitLength>` to the nearest Int using `MeasurementFormatter`. Given the following sample:

```
let distance = Measurement(value: 0.28, unit: .miles)

let formattedDistance = measurementFormatter.string(from: distance) // "492.8 yd"
```

What I am trying to achieve is "493 yd" instead of "492.8 yd"

I tried using `roundingMode` but didn't help with any of its modes:

```
measurementFormatter.numberFormatter.roundingMode = .up
```

Any help or idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `maximumFractionDigits` to `0` on the `NumberFormatter` as well as the `roundingMode` to `.up` to force the formatter to round decimal numbers up.

```
measurementFormatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
measurementFormatter.numberFormatter.roundingMode = .up
```

Comment: I tried both of them separately but not their combination! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If yards is a fixed unit you want, then you could just convert it directly.

```
 let distance = Measurement(value: 0.28, unit: .miles)
 let roundedYards = distance.converted(to: .yards).value.rounded() // "493 yd", rounded() will round up >= 0.5 and round down < 0.5
 let formattedDistance = Measurement(value: roundedValue, unit: .yards)
```